# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes(4,)(3,), In python2.7

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, typed-arrays

I have this code.I have posted the size for every element in this code in //
I now all of  them in size 3 instead of one is four. and  it must all to be in the same size or one of them is one.

when I tried to change the size from 3 to 4 using this line  i_arr-i_arr.resize(3).It cant work. 
please any help to solve this problem

```
def applyPadding(i, s, r) :
r_arr=np.asarray(r, dtype="int16") //[19,19,19]
i_arr=np.asarray(i.shape,dtype="int16") // [144,192,265,1]
r= np.array(r, dtype="int16") 
left_padding=(r - 1) / 2//[9,9,9]
right_padding=r - 1 - left_padding //[9,9,9]
extra_padding=np.maximum(0,np.asarray(s,dtype="int16")- 
(i_arr+left_padding+right_padding)) // s =[27, 27, 27]
right_padding+= extra_padding
paddingValues =((left_padding[0],right_padding[0]),
(left_padding[1],right_padding[1]),
(left_padding[2],right_padding[2]))
paddedImage = lib.pad(i, paddingValues, mode='reflect')
return [paddedImage, paddingValues]
```

the error I got is operands could not be broadcast together with shapes(4,)(3,)

Comment: Are you used to programming in C or something similar? Python doesn't **TYPICALLY** need padding or resizing.

Comment: this is code in python

Comment: it is neural network and we must do padding

Comment: Andras Deak  please could you help me

Comment: Are you the same guy, that posted this yesterday? I think you may want to write `i_arr=np.asarray(i.shape,dtype="int16")[:-1]` instead of `i_arr=np.asarray(i.shape,dtype="int16")`. Seems like a bug in the source

Comment: If you are not the same guy: you seem to have a colleague having the same problem. Inform him, if you find a solution

Comment: yes I am . I cant post from that account SO  I created this one

Comment: I could not find any one  to help me

Comment: raise ValueError(fmt % (shape,))
ValueError: Unable to create correctly shaped tuple from ((9, 9), (9, 9), (9, 9))

Comment: This script is either fundamentally broken and you need to tell your teacher or he gave you wrong instructions and you still need to ask him

Comment: I don't think, that this a good topic for SO as we can't possibly help you with this. We'd need to sit in front of your machine and debug the script step by step which may take days